# Javascript - Can't get average for array to alert

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm hoping this will be a pretty easy one for the experts out there. So, I've got my code to take in a number of student names and their respective marks. So far so good. But, when it gets to the end, it should put together the marks and find an average, then alert the average to the user. But, as it stands, I get no alert. Here's the code:

```
var sQuantity = parseInt(prompt("Let's begin compiling our student database. How many students would you like to enter?", "Number of Students")); 

var sList = new Array(); 
var sMarks = new Array(); 

for (var count = 0; count < sQuantity; count++) { 
    sList.push(prompt("Please enter the Student's Name", "Students Name")); 
} 

var i = 0; 

for (var count = 0; count < sQuantity; count++) { 
    sMarks.push(parseInt(prompt("Please enter " + sList[i] + "'s average grade for this course.", "Enter Average Grade"))); 
    var i=(i+1); 
} 

var sum = 0; 
var cAverage = 0; 

for (i = 0; i < sMarks.length; i++) { 
    sum = (sum + sMarks[i]); 
} 

cAverage = (Sum/sMarks.length); 

alert(cAverage);
```

Why does the code *not* display the average in the alert?

Comment: `cAverage = (Sum/sMarks.length); ` shouldn't that be `sum`

Comment: A little debugging with the console would've shown you the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variables are case sensitive, replace

```
cAverage = (Sum/sMarks.length);
```

with

```
cAverage = (sum/sMarks.length);
```

and it works

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/DWPFT/)

Comment: Nice eye, great catch :)

Comment: Yikes... I've been staring at this code for an hour and I missed that every time. I was ready to pull my hairs out. I was like... This should work! And just because of a different "S." Fresh eyes! Thank you.

Comment: Learn how to use the console to debug, and you would have spotted this in seconds.

Comment: Yes, the console. I have learned of it, I hadn't thought of it (still very new to me). Thanks for the reminder.